# Recommended Protocol\Binding Type For WCF

Tags: wcf, transactions, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I am developing services which will be consumed by many different platforms like Java,PHP,C or C++ etc. I want to know what protocol or binding type should I use for these kind of services. There should be a common protocol which can be used by all kind of technologies or most of them. I used BasicHTTPBindig for this purpose but this does not support transactions on client application. The supported Binding types are wsHttpBinding and others. I can use transactions supported types which are available with WCF but I don't know other technologies support them or not.

So the Question is What is the best Recommended Protocol or Binding type which support most of major technologies to consume WCF services.

Any kind of help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help to choose a binding(WCF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059981/help-to-choose-a-bindingwcf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect that by client side transaction you mean distributed transaction (flowing transaction started at client to server). This is quite challenging because interoperable support for distributed transactions requires WS-AtomicTransaction and WS-Coordinator protocols to be implemented by the platform. In short almost none service stack provides these protocols ([except WCF and several Java stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_frameworks)). So you will probably make this work with .NET, Java, C/C++ (but the configuration will not be easy) but you will have a hard time to use it in PHP, Python, etc. These protocols are also not supported on mobile devices.

Distributed transactions are considered as internal server to server feature. So if you are going to make public service you should change your design. If you are going to make public service / service consumed by client applications (not servers) then you should choose basic HTTP binding (or create REST service) for maximal interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at WCF for awhile (I don't know what - if anything - has changed in .Net 4.0, for example) ... but if you wanted to interface to non-MS/non-WCF clients, you used to need WSE (Web Services Enhancements).

Here's a good link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee958158.aspx